# How do I get these canvases to align properly?

Tags: html, css, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to display the three canvases over one another, but they just display beside each other. I have very little experience with css. What do I need to add?

```
<body>
<div id="canvas_container">
<canvas id="Background" width="330" height="330"></canvas>
<canvas id="mycanvas" width="330" height="330"></canvas>
<canvas id="Overlay" width="330" height="330"></canvas>
</div>

<style>
.canvas_container {
  position: relative;
}

.container > canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
</style>

<div id="codeinput">
<br>
The "X" goes here:<input type="text" id="shapeX">

<br>
The "Y" goes here:<input type="text" id="shapeY">

<br>
Choose the color: <input type="text" id="shapeColor" value="green">


<script>
unrelated javascript
</script>

<br>
<button onclick=makeSquare();>Draw shape</button>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your css ok but you set wrong selector. You has `id = canvas_container` but set styles for class `canvas_container` and class `container`

```css
#canvas_container {
  position: relative;
  width: 330px;
  height: 330px;
}

#canvas_container > canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="canvas_container">
  <canvas id="Background" width="330" height="330"></canvas>
  <canvas id="mycanvas" width="330" height="330"></canvas>
  <canvas id="Overlay" width="330" height="330"></canvas>
</div>

<div id="codeinput">
  <br>
  The "X" goes here:<input type="text" id="shapeX">
  <br>
  The "Y" goes here:<input type="text" id="shapeY">
  <br>
  Choose the color: <input type="text" id="shapeColor" value="green">
  <br>
  <button onclick=makeSquare();>Draw shape</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, now how do I get the text to display below the canvas?

Comment: @blobfishsandwich just set container width and height. Its not calculated by content sizes since content has `position: absolute`. I edit my answer with this fix

Comment: @blobfishsandwich and you need to set different `z-index` for all your canvases for control of them order by Z axis

Comment: Thanks! you have helped me a bunch.